# Laravel/PHP - very weird error - file input returning null

Tags: php, laravel, image-upload, multiple-file-upload

I have this view in my page in order to upload title image of album and then all images of album:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'AdminController@postProject', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'projectform']) }}
    {{ Form::file('title') }}
    {{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Add project') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In my controller is simply this:

```
public function postProject()  {

    $thumb = Input::file('title');
    $images = Input::file('images');
    dd($title);
```

When I upload sample images downloaded from internet (one in 'title' input and multiple in 'images' input), `dd($title)` returns normal informations about file. But...

.. when I try to upload another images, real images, that should be in my page (from camera device), `dd($title)` is returning null !!!. This happens only when one 'title' image is selected and multiple 'images' images are selected. When I select one title image and one 'image' image or no 'image' image, then it works!!! This issue happens only with real images from camera.

What could be wrong here? Why it returns null for 'title' image?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: problem was with upload limit. In .htaccess now I have:

```
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
```